# python3 list filter lambda getting TypeError: 'wrapper_descriptor' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

The following code works in python2 but doesn't work in python3. I need some help, thanks.

```py
class A:
    a = (0, "a")
    b = (1, "b")

choice = 1

hit = len(list(filter(lambda x: getattr(A, x) is not None and getattr(A, x)[0]==choice, dir(A))))>0
print(hit)
```

In python 2

```
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.16
$ python2 b.py 
True
```

But in python3

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.0
$ python3 b.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/tmp/a/b.py", line 7, in <module>
    hit = len(list(filter(lambda x: getattr(A, x) is not None and getattr(A, x)[0]==choice, dir(A))))>0
  File "/private/tmp/a/b.py", line 7, in <lambda>
    hit = len(list(filter(lambda x: getattr(A, x) is not None and getattr(A, x)[0]==choice, dir(A))))>0
TypeError: 'wrapper_descriptor' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: How about looping on `dir(A)` and printing `print(x, getattr(A, x))`  to find the faulty attribute...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I want to understand the reason why python3 gives error while python2 works.

Comment: I understand, so obviously one of the attributes which is a `wrapper_descriptor` is not subscriptible. Print the attributes to find which one it is... As to why it works in Python 2, I would guess that the type of that attribute has changed... By the way I'm getting `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`...

Comment: Why on earth are you using `dir(A)`?

Comment: Did you by any means, meant to loop over [`vars(A)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars)?

Comment: Yes, looping over `for name, attribute in vars(A).items(): ...` would make a lot more sense here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing a difference between Python 2 and Python 3 is that in Python 3, classes implicitly inherit the `object` class.  In Python 2 you have:

```
>>> dir(A)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'a', 'b']
>>>
```

In this case, both `__doc__` and `__module__` have value `None`, so your filter test works.

But in Python 3 you have everything from the `object` class as well:

```
>>> dir(A)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'a', 'b']
>>>
```

Some of these attributes are neither `None` nor subscriptable.  For example, the `__class__` attribute is a type, and is not subscriptable, which is probably where your error is coming from.

Ideally you would use a known list of attributes, without relying on `dir()`, but if you want to check everything, you could do something such as ignore attributes that begin with `__`.  That could take the place of the `is not None` test.  For example, the following works in both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
hit = len(list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith("__") and getattr(A, x)[0]==choice, dir(A))))>0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because some attribute returned by `dir(A)` is not subscriptable in Python 3. Running the following code:

```
class A:
    a = (0, "a")
    b = (1, "b")

for x in dir(A):
    print(x, getattr(A, x))
```

in Python 2:

```
('__doc__', None)
('__module__', '__main__')
('a', (0, 'a'))
('b', (1, 'b'))
```

in Python 3:

```
__delattr__ <slot wrapper '__delattr__' of 'object' objects>
__dict__ {'__module__': '__main__', 'a': (0, 'a'), 'b': (1, 'b'), '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None}
__dir__ <method '__dir__' of 'object' objects>
__doc__ None
__eq__ <slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>
__format__ <method '__format__' of 'object' objects>
__ge__ <slot wrapper '__ge__' of 'object' objects>
__getattribute__ <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>
__gt__ <slot wrapper '__gt__' of 'object' objects>
__hash__ <slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'object' objects>
__init__ <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects>
__init_subclass__ <built-in method __init_subclass__ of type object at 0x000001E7B0D96EB8>
__le__ <slot wrapper '__le__' of 'object' objects>
__lt__ <slot wrapper '__lt__' of 'object' objects>
__module__ __main__
__ne__ <slot wrapper '__ne__' of 'object' objects>
__new__ <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x0000000077E99D90>
__reduce__ <method '__reduce__' of 'object' objects>
__reduce_ex__ <method '__reduce_ex__' of 'object' objects>
__repr__ <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'object' objects>
__setattr__ <slot wrapper '__setattr__' of 'object' objects>
__sizeof__ <method '__sizeof__' of 'object' objects>
__str__ <slot wrapper '__str__' of 'object' objects>
__subclasshook__ <built-in method __subclasshook__ of type object at 0x000001E7B0D96EB8>
__weakref__ <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>
a (0, 'a')
b (1, 'b')
```

so obviously it no longer works with all the new returns that are not subscriptable.

To get the attributes as you want, maybe consider to use

```
[x for x in A.__dict__.keys() if x[:2]!='__']
```

to replace the `dir(A)` in your code:

```
class A:
    a = (0, "a")
    b = (1, "b")

choice = 1

attributes = [x for x in A.__dict__.keys() if x[:2]!='__']
hit = len(list(filter(lambda x: getattr(A, x) is not None and getattr(A, x)[0]==choice, attributes)))>0
print(hit)
```

Comment: modified as @Tomerikoo suggested

Answer (score 0):

```
for var in dir(A):
    print(getattr(A,var))
```

give this output:

```
<class 'type'>
<slot wrapper '__delattr__' of 'object' objects>
{'__module__': '__main__', 'a': (0, 'a'), 'b': (1, 'b'), '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None}
<method '__dir__' of 'object' objects>
None
<slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>
<method '__format__' of 'object' objects>
<slot wrapper '__ge__' of 'object' objects>
<slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>
<slot wrapper '__gt__' of 'object' objects>
<slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'object' objects>
<slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects>
<built-in method __init_subclass__ of type object at 0x7fe38c708340>
<slot wrapper '__le__' of 'object' objects>
<slot wrapper '__lt__' of 'object' objects>
__main__
<slot wrapper '__ne__' of 'object' objects>
<built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x104bf0218>
<method '__reduce__' of 'object' objects>
<method '__reduce_ex__' of 'object' objects>
<slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'object' objects>
<slot wrapper '__setattr__' of 'object' objects>
<method '__sizeof__' of 'object' objects>
<slot wrapper '__str__' of 'object' objects>
<built-in method __subclasshook__ of type object at 0x7fe38c708340>
<attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>
(0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
```

Your is not None condition alway True.You should use another one obviously.

So just change not None condition:

```
hit = len(list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith("__") and getattr(A, x)[0]==choice, dir(A))))>0
```

Comment: So how should I test if an attribute is subscriptable or not?

Comment: @QianChen Subscriptable basically means that the object implements the __getitem__() method.

Comment: `hasattr(obj, "__getitem__")` should work.

Comment: @Carcigenicate how should it apply to my code? Thanks.

Comment: @Carcigenicate You are right.However it's not the Pythonic way to do things; Python practice encourages Duck Typing. Meaning, if you plan on trying to fetch an item from your object using a subscript, go ahead and do it; if you think it might not work because the object is not subscriptable, wrap it in a  try block with an except TypeError.

Comment: @QianChen Or, instead of trying to cram everything in one line, just use a normal loop with a `try/except`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I prefer one line, if possible.

Comment: @QianChen yeah, well, don't. I mean, you *can* write bad code in one line if you want. But you should prefer clarity and maintainability over the number of lines (a pretty useless metric).

Comment: @RomanFerenets That's not duck typing, that's "asking forgiveness rather than permission". Python also encourages not blindly following set rules. Do whatever leads to the cleaner code. (Duck typing is having classes that aren't related, but have the same attributes, and that can be used in the same way).

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think you don't fully understand what is Duck Typing.Have a look - https://realpython.com/lessons/duck-typing/.

Comment: @Carcigenicate "having classes that aren't related, but have the same attributes, and that can be used in the same way" - is called polymorphism.

Comment: @RomanFerenets I am quite familiar with the topic. From your link "... where the type or the class of an object is less important than the methods it defines.", which is nearly exactly what I had written above. You can use `try` to handle bad duck typing cases, but that isn't at all related to duck typing itself.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah, I think you are right, Duck Typing wasn't right term there.Thanks for broad response anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has already pointed out `Python3` classes inherit from `object` and therefore contain many more attributes than `Python2` classes. Some of which aren't subscriptable.

Below I have ported your code to 3 using `__dict__.keys()` and `list comprehension`.

```
sum(getattr(A, x, [0])[0] for x in [i if not i.startswith("__") else "" for i in A.__dict__.keys()])>0
```